# Mercure Docker Invalid JWT Signature from ignoring JWT_KEY from docker-compose

Tags: docker, docker-compose, jwt, mercure

I have a docker-compose which fires up a mercure container

#### docker-compose

```
version: '3.8'

services:
    ...
    mercure:
        image: dunglas/mercure
        ports:
            - '8003:443'
            - '8004:80'
        environment:
            - JWT_KEY='so_secret'
            - DEMO=1
            - DEBUG=1
            - ALLOW_ANONYMOUS=1
            - CORS_ALLOWED_ORIGINS=*
            - PUBLISH_ALLOWED_ORIGINS=*
networks:
    default:
```

But when I POST to `POST http://mercure/.well-known/mercure` I get this from my mercure container:
(prettified)

```
Log #1
{
   "level":"info",
   "ts":1606379852.84174,
   "logger":"http.handlers.mercure",
   "msg":"Topic selectors not matched or not provided",
   "remote_addr":"192.168.192.3:37534",
   "error":"unable to parse JWT: signature is invalid"
}

Log #2
{
   "level":"error",
   "ts":1606379852.8418272,
   "logger":"http.log.access",
   "msg":"handled request",
   "request":{
      "remote_addr":"192.168.192.3:37534",
      "proto":"HTTP/1.1",
      "method":"POST",
      "host":"mercure",
      "uri":"/.well-known/mercure",
      "headers":{
         "Authorization":[
            "Bearer eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJtZXJjdXJlIjp7InB1Ymxpc2giOltdfX0.VuGJakeE0mowuQj0ErJjtEE-U4iYey2_XCbESaaGvtU"
         ],
         "User-Agent":[
            "Symfony HttpClient/Curl"
         ],
         "Accept-Encoding":[
            "gzip"
         ],
         "Content-Length":[
            "1339"
         ],
         "Content-Type":[
            "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
         ],
         "Accept":[
            "*/*"
         ]
      }
   },
   "common_log":"192.168.192.3 - - [26/Nov/2020:08:37:32 +0000] \"POST /.well-known/mercure HTTP/1.1\" 401 13",
   "duration":0.001635684,
   "size":13,
   "status":401,
   "resp_headers":{
      "X-Content-Type-Options":[
         "nosniff"
      ],
      "X-Xss-Protection":[
         "1; mode=block"
      ],
      "Content-Security-Policy":[
         "default-src 'self' mercure.rocks cdn.jsdelivr.net"
      ],
      "Content-Type":[
         "text/plain; charset=utf-8"
      ],
      "Server":[
         "Caddy"
      ],
      "X-Frame-Options":[
         "DENY"
      ]
   }
}
```

Why does it say the Signature is invalid, when https://jwt.io/ says it is verified? Does the `JWT_KEY` from the docker-compose get ignored?

// EDIT
`sudo docker-compose exec mercure env` shows `JWT_KEY=so_secret`, so what else can I check?

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue. I tried things like:

- restarting,
- recreating,
- link changing

(thought that mercure container had some cache.)

Then I go to documentation and get the example of payload.

So I change my **JWT_KEY**, and rebuild **Authorization** token, based on new example and it starts working!!

[Working payload](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4bCFE.png)

Comment: Hey, thank you, I tried it with a new Payload (added the `subscribe`), still no luck. Where does it describe this in the docs, what is the payload?